# How to use mixed mode .net assembly in Qt 4.8.4 application?

Tags: .net, qt, directx, qsettings

In my Qt application I use .net assembly wrapped in COM which uses Microsoft.DirectX library.
When I launch my application it crashes with the following details in output

```
<mda:msg xmlns:mda="http://schemas.microsoft.com/CLR/2004/10/mda">
  <!-- 
       DLL 'D:\MyAppPath\..\Microsoft.DirectX.dll' is
       attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run
       managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so
       can cause the application to hang.
   -->
 <mda:loaderLockMsg break="true"/>
</mda:msg>
myApp.exe has triggered a breakpoint
```

As far as I know Microsoft.DirectX library for .Net is 1.1 version and the assembly is 4.0 and that is the root of the problem.

I tried to use this assembly in simple c++ winForms application and the same problem was resolved by adding the app.config file with following code

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
 </startup>
```

But Qt doesn't seem to support app.config files. How could I set this **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy** in Qt configuration? I tried through QSettings and it didnt worked out. Or may be there are some other workaround for Qt?

I Also tried to disable LoaderLock Exception (Debug->Exceptions->Managed Debugging Assistants). But it didn't worked out too.

Thanks

Comment: Officially the legacy DirectX Managed 1.1 assemblies do not support .NET 4.0. See this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx) post for details.

You could look at using [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/) or some other alternative...